# SWT composite ordering in layout

Tags: java, layout, swt

I have a composite that contains two child composites

```
+---+---+
| 1 | 2 |
+---+---+
```

How can I change the order of these two composites when the user clicks a button? 
Result should be:

```
+---+---+
| 2 | 1 |
+---+---+
```

Thanks
Simon

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change the order of element in RowLayout SWT Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250946/change-the-order-of-element-in-rowlayout-swt-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Control class has methods moveAbove() and moveBelow(), I think these two are doing exactly what you need

Answer (score 3):

I think this answers your question: [Change the order of element in RowLayout SWT Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9254219)

It basically says, that there is a `z-order` you can use to position your components.

Answer (score 1):

Control.moveAbove() and Control.moveBelow() works for changing order of controls in Composite children(). Parent composite should be done re-layout to compute new bounds for children.